# Visual studio DLL problem

Tags: visual-studio-2010

i have a problem with a DLL.

i have created an DLL agent snmp extension with visual studio and for testing debug DLL i connect it to snmp service, but if open Debug->Module my DLL is not present in the list, so the breakpoint are not avaible.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Debug your DLL you had to debug SNMP.EXE. for that Debug->Attach to process. Keep the pdb file close to the DLL.